# How to lint expressions in Vue's template by using ESLint?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint

There is some JS/TS expression in Vue's template. like `{{ a.b }}`, `v-if="a === -0"`etc. I want ESLint can lint expressions in Vue's template. Like the picture, typescript code in `<script setup lang="ts">` can be recognized and lint by Eslint, I can see the tips. But the same code in `<template>` is not be lint. how should I do to solve this?
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqSWs.png)

I expect the expression in template can be recognized and lint.

Comment: I recommend trying antfu's https://github.com/antfu/eslint-config , see https://github.com/antfu/vitesse template

Answer (score 0):

To enable ESLint to lint expressions in Vue templates, you can follow these steps:

1. **Install necessary packages**: Make sure you have the required packages installed. You'll need `eslint-plugin-vue` to enable Vue-specific linting rules.

   ```
   npm install eslint-plugin-vue --save-dev
   ```
2. **Configure ESLint**: Update your ESLint configuration file (`.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json`) to include the necessary rules and settings for Vue templates.

   ```
   {
     // Other existing ESLint rules and configurations
     "plugins": ["vue"],
     "extends": ["plugin:vue/recommended"],
     "parserOptions": {
       "parser": "babel-eslint"
     }
   }
   ```

   Here, `"plugin:vue/recommended"` enables recommended Vue-specific ESLint rules provided by `eslint-plugin-vue`. `"babel-eslint"` is set as the parser to correctly parse the Vue template expressions.
3. **Configure VS Code (Optional)**: If you're using Visual Studio Code, you can install the "Vetur" extension. It provides improved Vue support and integrates with ESLint to display linting errors in the editor.
4. **Lint Vue templates**: Run ESLint to lint your Vue templates. It should now be able to lint expressions and provide linting errors and warnings for your Vue template code.

If you still encounter issues with ESLint not linting correctly in Vue templates, check if you have the necessary plugin installed (`eslint-plugin-vue`) and confirm that your `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json` configuration file is correctly set up as described above.

Additionally, make sure that you have properly configured any other required ESLint plugins or rules for your project and that you have restarted any related development servers or editors to ensure they pick up the latest ESLint configurations.

By following these steps, you should be able to enable ESLint to lint expressions in Vue templates and see linting errors and warnings in your development environment.

Comment: It's not helpful...